# Visual Force: Checking boxes individually triggers OnChange, but my CheckAllboxes page component does not

Tags: visualforce, inputcheckboxes

I have a table of items. Each item can be selected or checked with a checkbox, and an OnChange is triggered to pass its ID to Apex for a query that will quote the selected items.

This works all fine for individual checking. However I just added a page component that checks all the items if the "Select All" box is checked. This "works" also, it ticks all the boxes on the table. However the OnChange is not triggered so no ID's are passed to Apex for the query resulting in no quote data.

Visual Force Page Snippet:

```
<apex: page>
    <table>
        <tr class="headerRow">
            <th style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center" width="4%">
                <br/>Select<br/>
                <c:CheckAllOrNone />
            </th>
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!data}" var="Results">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center" width="4%"><input type="checkbox" value="{!Results.Id}" onChange="quotesCheck('{!Results.id}', this.checked);" /></td>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
</apex:page>
```

Page Component:

```
<apex:component >
    <script>
    function cvCheckAllOrNone(allOrNoneCheckbox) {

        // Find parent table
        var container = allOrNoneCheckbox;
        while (container.tagName != "TABLE") {
            container = container.parentNode;
        }

        // Switch all checkboxes
        var inputs = container.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var checked = allOrNoneCheckbox.checked;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { 
            var input = inputs.item(i);
            if (input.type == "checkbox") {
                if (input != allOrNoneCheckbox) {
                    input.checked = checked;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>

    <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="cvCheckAllOrNone(this)" title="Toggle All Rows"/>
</apex:component>
```

Apex Snippet:

```
public PageReference addQuotesToChecked()
{
    string quoteId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('quoteId');
    string chkValue = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('chkValue');
    System.debug('quoteId '+quoteId);
    System.debug('chkValue '+chkValue);
    if(checkedQuotes ==null)
    {
        checkedQuotes= new List<id>();
        checkedQuotes.add(quoteId);
    }
    else
    {
        if(chkValue=='true')
        {
            checkedQuotes.add(quoteId);
        }
        else
        {
           integer i= checkedQuotes.indexOf(quoteId);
            checkedQuotes.remove(i);
        }

    }
    integer i=checkedQuotes.size();

    return null;
}
```

Apex Function:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!addQuotesToChecked}" name="quotesCheck" 
reRender="sasa">
   <apex:param name="quoteId" value=""/> 
   <apex:param name="chkValue" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Comment: This is normal JavaScript behavior, not calling a UI event because of script changes to DOM data. You'll need to rethink your entire design, because it simply isn't going to work as is without major modifications.

Comment: From the HTML documentation: "The onchange event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. " So I think you'll have to trigger the action from your cvCheckAllOrNone component.

Answer (score 1):

A quick 'n dirty solution would be to switch to 'onclick' instead of 'onchange' and trigger the 'click()' action in your script.

```
            <td style="text-align: center" width="4%"><input type="checkbox" value="{!Results.Id}" onClick="quotesCheck('{!Results.id}', this.checked);" /></td>
```

and

```
            if (input != allOrNoneCheckbox) {
                input.click();
            }
```

Comment: This works, but a new problem is that only one ID is passed in. And the ID seems to be random from the selection. I've put in a debug and all the IDs are in the java script so I don't know why only one is being sent to apex.

Comment: That's weird.. Could you include your apex:actionFunction in the example above? I think it's missing..

Comment: Added my apex action function

Comment: Remember that when you call an `actionFunction` it triggers a postback of the entire view state, and then a partial or full re-render comes back to the UI. You simply can't trigger multiples and expect a consistent result. If you simultaneously trigger that handler on many boxes at once, the first postback that commences will be the one that "wins" with all the other boxes still unchecked. Ideally your "Select All" should tick them all WITHOUT triggering individual postbacks, and then trigger ONE postback that handles the select-all in bulk.

Comment: Good point. That's what is most probably causing this behavior.